# Salesforce- Merlion: How to correct the timestamp duplicates?

Tags: python, database, time-series, timestamp, salesforce-merlion

I am trying to run [this example](https://opensource.salesforce.com/Merlion/v1.1.0/examples/anomaly/0_AnomalyIntro.html) of the Salesforce- Merlion documentation.

At the beginning of the code we have:

```
from merlion.utils import TimeSeries
from ts_datasets.anomaly import NAB

time_series, metadata = NAB(subset="realKnownCause")[3]
train_data = TimeSeries.from_pd(time_series[metadata.trainval])
test_data = TimeSeries.from_pd(time_series[~metadata.trainval])
test_labels = TimeSeries.from_pd(metadata.anomaly[~metadata.trainval])
```

When I run this code, it returns this error below, and it is the same of the documentation's example:

```
Time series /Users/abhatnagar/Desktop/Merlion/data/nab/realKnownCause/ec2_request_latency_system_failure.csv (index 2) has timestamp duplicates. Kept first values.
Time series /Users/abhatnagar/Desktop/Merlion/data/nab/realKnownCause/machine_temperature_system_failure.csv (index 3) has timestamp duplicates. Kept first values.
```

I am not understanding if I have to correct this file and what handling I can do to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to worry about these errors: they are expected. It has to do with the fact that the NAB dataset can have duplicate timestamps. Since in any timeseries the `timestamp -> value` has to be a 1-1 relatoinship, the dataset loader drops duplicate values for any particular timestamp and only keeps the first.

You can see what's happening in the code here: https://github.com/salesforce/Merlion/blob/4a448de1676e62b6305578e3a21dd92d4d2ac245/ts_datasets/ts_datasets/anomaly/nab.py#L85